# How to connect television to laptop via HDMI cable to display videos from laptop with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, external-monitor

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

I have connected my laptop with my HDMI cable to the television.

But unlike in Windows 7, I can't find HDMI as an output anywhere in the settings, neither for video nor audio. Can anyone please offer step by step instructions on how to do this? I just want to "stream" videos, for example from YouTube, from my laptop to my television.

Comment: Have you checked this thread? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1993084

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a proprietary video card?  I have an nvidia card.  I can't use the standard ubuntu display settings.  I have to have the proprietary drivers installed and use the nvidia X Server Settings dialog to choose the correct output.  I assume it may be the same with AMD video card.

It doesn't explicitly say HDMI output but when I have it hooked up, it gives me the option to choose a secondary display.

Comment: Thx for the a.nswer. What is a propriatery videocard ? Do you mean there is a chance that my videocard is nit supported by ubuntu, and thati have  to get soesific drivers for rhat card? what is the easiest way to do that? :-)

Comment: Hello again. My laptop is a hp pavillon dv 6700. It seems like it has got an integraced videochip on the motherboard? When I in Ubuntu 12.04 looks after graphics settings the system says it cant find any info about it. Any tip on how to solve the problem, so that i can find some graphicsdrivers that suits this laptop, so that i get the option to find and choose hdmi as an output option? Appreciate any feedback, since i have been having this problem for quite some time now :/

Comment: It seems like the graphics on my laptop is nVidia Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400M GS . Now i wonder, how do i install the latest of these drivers on ubuntu 12.04, what do i type in the terminal?  And what do i do after they are installed? Appreciate any help.

Comment: press your super key to bring up the Unity Dash.  Type 'drivers' you should see something like 'additional drivers'  choose it.  It should find nvidia proprietary drivers.  Install, log out and in again.  Then hit the Unity dash again and type nvidia, you should see the nvidia settings manager.  go from there.  Hope it helps

Comment: Hello :) I tried the nvidia x server settings dialog, as mentioned from another user above. And that solved my problem. Thx :)